# AWS S3 storage does not give a valid URL after uploading file

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I am new to AWS. I use `Amplify` to upload a video file to `S3 storage` using `Flutter`. I want to get the URL after uploading a video to use it elsewhere. I use `Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key)).url` to get the URL. But when I want to go to the link via the browser, it shows the following error there:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>No AWSAccessKey was presented.</Message>
    <RequestId>AK49EW70AR8N1NVC</RequestId>
    <HostId>Z6FBLU/GABRvJKFX827m3HoIKfVIpU0iXmH3gwSpcu04nNiqqEFjHZGGLn3VyyVNMY7ndK541ro= 
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

And also this link doesn't work when I want to play a video using `VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl)`.
So what is the solution to get a general URL for the video file uploaded that can be used elsewhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to s3 bucket to check if its private or public maybe you can change the setting there

Comment: most of time any access related issue(403) you may need to check with the permission, not sure how you are accessing the bucket (not expert on Flutter), please check bucket policy if any.